# Weird App Behavior My App Sometimes Just Act Abnormal

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart

So recently I just made my first app using flutter. The app is about Muslim prayer time schedules.

I made the app myself and have no one to back me up when I face a problem like this.. hopefully, someone can help me solve this.

so the method is to collect schedule data from Web API and encode it Json pattern to my app but sometimes my app is just stuck at the loading screen and won't go to another screen / UI. even though I've already checked the internet connection and if the internet connection slow at a time span using timeout method to go to another screen if fail to connect it sometimes just won't go.

this problem actually rarely happens but eventually, it will cause a problem and decrease the users experience with the app.
this is the code that I think has the problem:

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart' as geo;
import 'package:yaumi/services/shared/preferenceServices.dart';
//import 'package:location/location.dart';

class FirstLoad extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstLoad();

  @override
  _FirstLoadState createState() => _FirstLoadState();
}

class _FirstLoadState extends State<FirstLoad> {
  final geo.GeolocatorPlatform _geolocatorPlatform = geo.GeolocatorPlatform.instance;
  bool serviceEnabled;
  geo.LocationPermission _permission;
  geo.Position _currentPosition;

  //Location _location;
  var lat;
  var lon;
  var ele;
  var date;
  
  bool isApiSatu = true;
  bool isConnected = true;

  final String tahun = DateTime.now().year.toString();
  final String bulan = DateTime.now().month.toString();
  final String tanggal = DateTime.now().day.toString();

  String sharedShubuh= '';
  String sharedDhuhur= '';
  String sharedAshar= '';
  String sharedMaghrib= '';
  String sharedIsya= '';

  void setupsWaktuShalat() async {
    //serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    // if (!serviceEnabled) {
    //   serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
    //   if (!serviceEnabled) {
    //     return print('Service Permission is not given');
    //   }
    // }

    //TODO: Untuk HP China seperti Xiaomi atau Huawei biasanya harus setting manual dulu pengaturan batterai nya

    // _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    // if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
    //     _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
    //     if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    //       return print('Permission request not granted');
    //     }
    //   }

    

    

    serviceEnabled = await _geolocatorPlatform.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if(!serviceEnabled) {
      return print('_geolocator service not enabled');
    }

    _permission = await _geolocatorPlatform.checkPermission();
    if(_permission==geo.LocationPermission.denied){
      _permission = await _geolocatorPlatform.requestPermission();
      if (_permission==geo.LocationPermission.denied) {
        return print('permission not granted');
      }
    }

    await geo.Geolocator
      .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: geo.LocationAccuracy.medium, forceAndroidLocationManager: true)
      .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5))
      .then((geo.Position position) {
        setState(() {
          //print('position: $position');
          _currentPosition = position;
          print('_currentPosition: $_currentPosition');
        });
      }).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
      });

    if (_currentPosition != null) {
      lat = _currentPosition.latitude;
      lon = _currentPosition.longitude;
    } else {
      lat = '-6.864008';
      lon = '107.591192';
    }
    
    //print('$lat and $lon');
    ele = 333;
    date = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(new DateTime.now());

    //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');

    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        //print('connected');
        isConnected = true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      //print('not connected');
      isConnected = false;
    }

    if (isConnected) {
      try {
        Response response =     
          await get(
            Uri.parse(
              'https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/day.json?longitude=$lon&latitude=$lat&elevation=$ele&date=$date'
            )
          ).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
        
        Map map = jsonDecode(response.body);
        //print(map);
        Map _results = map['results'];
        //print(_results);
        List _datetimeList = _results['datetime'];
        Map _datetime = _datetimeList[0];
        Map _times = _datetime['times'];

        setState(() {
          sharedShubuh = _times['Fajr'];
          sharedDhuhur = _times['Dhuhr'];
          sharedAshar = _times['Asr'];
          sharedMaghrib = _times['Maghrib'];
          sharedIsya = _times['Isha'];
        });

        try {
          await PreferenceServices.setShubuh(sharedShubuh);
          await PreferenceServices.setDhuhur(sharedDhuhur);
          await PreferenceServices.setAshar(sharedAshar);
          await PreferenceServices.setMaghrib(sharedMaghrib);
          await PreferenceServices.setIsya(sharedIsya);
        } catch (e) {
          print('error karena $e');
        }

        //print(_times);
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
          'Shubuh': sharedShubuh,
          'Dhuhur': sharedDhuhur,
          'Ashar': sharedAshar,
          'Maghrib': sharedMaghrib,
          'Isya': sharedIsya,
          'Connection': true
        });
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          setState(() {
            isApiSatu = false;        
          });
          Response response =     
            await get(
              Uri.parse(
                'https://api.myquran.com/v1/sholat/jadwal/1219/$tahun/$bulan/$tanggal'
              )
            ).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
          
          Map map = jsonDecode(response.body);
          print(map);
          Map _data = map['data'];
          Map _jadwal = _data['jadwal'];
          print(_jadwal);

          setState(() {
            sharedShubuh = _jadwal['subuh'];
            sharedDhuhur = _jadwal['dzuhur'];
            sharedAshar = _jadwal['ashar'];
            sharedMaghrib = _jadwal['maghrib'];
            sharedIsya = _jadwal['isya'];
          });

          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
            'Shubuh': sharedShubuh,
            'Dhuhur': sharedDhuhur,
            'Ashar': sharedAshar,
            'Maghrib': sharedMaghrib,
            'Isya': sharedIsya,
            'Connection': true
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
            'Shubuh': sharedShubuh,
            'Dhuhur': sharedDhuhur,
            'Ashar': sharedAshar,
            'Maghrib': sharedMaghrib,
            'Isya': sharedIsya,
            'Connection': true
          });
        }
      }
    } else {
      //print('sharedDhuhur:$sharedDhuhur');
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
        'Shubuh': sharedShubuh,
        'Dhuhur': sharedDhuhur,
        'Ashar': sharedAshar,
        'Maghrib': sharedMaghrib,
        'Isya': sharedIsya,
        'Connection': false
      });
    }
    
    
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
    PreferenceServices.getShubuh().then((e) =>
      sharedShubuh = e.toString()
    );
    PreferenceServices.getDhuhur().then((e) =>
      sharedDhuhur = e.toString()
    );
    PreferenceServices.getAshar().then((e) =>
      sharedAshar = e.toString()
    );
    PreferenceServices.getMaghrib().then((e) =>
      sharedMaghrib = e.toString()
    );
    PreferenceServices.getIsya().then((e) =>
      sharedIsya = e.toString()
    );
    
    setupsWaktuShalat();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              colors: [Color(0xFF6441A5), Color(0xFF2a0845)]),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: SpinKitFadingCube(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the link to my app for further check the app:

[text](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zatunrstudio.yaumi)

Comment: Basically you use asynchronous queries to retrieve your prayer data and so you have no control as to when the data will actually be received by your app. The other ways I could suggest is bypassing asynchronous data queries and maybe using pre-tabled values of prayer times where the values are already known.

Comment: Thx for reply @Ezani ... I am not really sure on how to properly gain control over the data from the API because the prayer time depend so much on API or to properly bypass them.
But inside my code I already take some alternative if the API not responding or if the internet connection is not available to push to other UI Screen with a null data on prayer times anyway. but if it work the first time the data will be stored as a sharedpreferences. It's a very hackery non proper solution I could think of
Even the flutter geolocator sometimes just wont trigger at all. I started to think its a bug

Comment: For locations, you could you the Google Location API or Google Map API. Also as regards the API pushing the prayer times, I am pretty certain they are also getting their data from an already calculated table of prayer times for the year for the different major cities and towns although if you want to do the calculation yourself, I think it would be pretty complicated - getting your geo-coords and getting the direction of the sun and the direction of Mecca, etc. So I would suggest you pulling the salah data from tables which will lead to a much faster and stable app.